# Salesforce multipicklist field to text input prefill in form assembly

Tags: form

I have a salesforce multi-picklist field Cost__c with values A and B. I have a form assembly with a text field Cost which should get value from the multi-picklist values chosen in Salesforce. Suppose A and B are chosen the form field should show A; B or the individual values chosen.
But if I directly map the salesforce field into the prefill connector form field, I am not getting both values.

I tried using some formulas in the prefill connector like {!Cost__c.join(A__c,B__c)} but it returns the same formula in the output field and doesn't execute the formula.

I know if I change it to a multi-select list in the form it is possible. But I cant change the question type.
Also if I use a formula field to store the multi-picklist values and assign the form assembly text field to this formula field I know it is possible. But I cant create another salesforce field also.

So is there any way I can do this without changing the type of the form field(As of now text input) and creating a new formula field?

[image]

Comment: You will have to check with Form Assembly support.

Comment: @DavidCheng Okay will do that. Thanks